# Estimate total effect of treatment when continuous treatment variable and its dichotomization show contradicting impacts

Tags: modeling, binary-data, continuous-data, difference-in-difference

I am trying to estimate the total effect of a leak of a harmful gas on my dependent variable. While I do not know the actual exposure, I know the distance of a household to the origin of the leak in meters. The exposure is not perfectly correlated with distance but I know that this is still a reliable measure for it.

I am using a difference-in-differences design to estimate its effect:

$Y_{ijt}$ = $\theta_t$ + $\delta Z_{jt}$  + $\mu_{i}$  + $\varepsilon_{ijt}$

Where $Y_{ijt}$ is the dependent variable for person i in household j at time t. 
$\theta_t$ and $\mu_{i}$ are time and individual FE. The variable of interest, $Z_{jt}$, is zero in the pre-treatment period, and is equal to the distance of a household to the origin of the leak in the treatment period. Distance in this case is continuous, and I treat household with more than M meters distance as controls.

I also estimate the following model:

$Y_{ijt}$ = $\theta_t$ + $\delta D_{jt}$  + $\mu_{i}$  + $\varepsilon_{ijt}$

Where the only difference is, that I dichotomize the continuous distance variable. It is equal to 1 if the household is within a M meter distance and 0 otherwise.

Now comes the confusing part. The first model indicates that the closer a household is to the origin of the leak, the higher my dependent variable. I.e. a X meter decrease in distance, leads to a positive change in $Y_{ijt}$.

The second model (dummy) indicates that the treatment had a negative impact on those within the treatment group.

I believe that people within the treatment group experienced a drop in their dependent variable, while for those closer to the leak the effects gets increasingly weaker.

Now I want to get the total effect, and I am wondering on how to do this. My current approach is the following:

$Y_{ijt}$ = $\theta_t$ + $\delta Z_{jt}$  +  $\delta D_{jt}$ + $\mu_{i}$  + $\varepsilon_{ijt}$

I add both the continuous variable $Z_{jt}$ and the binary variable $D_{jt}$, sum up the coefficients, and perform a test for joint significance (the variables are highly correlated and not significant on their own). The magnitudes of both coefficients are similar and have the sign as in the individual estimations.

Is this approach correct?

Edit: I have evidence in favor of the common trend assumption. I have also posted this on reddit.com/r/econometrics/. And will post the answer here, should I get a response.

Comment: What is "total effect"? Last model is unacceptable. Define the distance being zero in the pre-treatment period = leaking is happened in all households before "pre-treatment period". is it reasonable?

Comment: The total effect would be the effect of the binary variable + the effect of the continuous variable, as these two point to opposite directions. There is no period before the pre-treatment period, as I only have 2 periods. Why exactly is the last model unacceptable? I am trying to understand whether what I am doing is technically correct.

Comment: OK. Try to draw the lines $E(Y) = \theta + \delta(Z+D)+\mu$ for given $\theta$ and $\mu$, to see if the lines are what you want.